# withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead) not working for Contabo Object storage

Tags: amazon-s3

Below is my source code:

```
public void uploadFile(String filedir, String name, byte[] content) {
    File file = new File(name);
    try (FileOutputStream iofs = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        iofs.write(content);
        PutObjectRequest putObj =
                new PutObjectRequest(defaultBucketName, defaultBaseFolder + "/" + filedir + "/" + file.getName(), file)
                        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        PutObjectResult putObjectResult =
                amazonS3Client.putObject(putObj);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Expected Behavior:** After executing the above code, the file stored at [Contabo](https://contabo.com/en/object-storage/) object storage should be "Public".

**Actual Behavior:** But it is not Public after upload. It remains as private as below:
[Click here to see object storage state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM8tb.png)

**aws-java-sdk** version: 1.12.215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this issue. I spent few hours trying to figure out why the "Public Access" button is still inactive while exactly following [Contabo's official documentation](https://docs.contabo.com/docs/products/Object-Storage/HowTo/public-sharing/)

As it turned out, files were available for download after adding them with correct ACL's even though the Public Access button is not green. I used the code below

```
public String store(MultipartFile file, String filePath) {
  try {
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, filePath, file.getInputStream(), null)
      .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

    s3client.putObject(request);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }

  return filePath;
}
```

As far as I know, in order to access uploaded resource you need to build URL by yourself. I followed the sheme visible in the URL generated in Contabo UI using "Make Public" slider.